# MySQL Connect Error = Can't connect and Access denied, even w/o using PASSWORDS

Tags: php, mysql

I just upgraded my WAMP server and imported back my databases and tables.

I didn't import the user / priv tables because i wanted a fresh start.

I properly set the root user, and that works.

I set the mysql USER (main_user) and PASS (aa11) properly for a DB w/ the right privileges (grant all)

But when I run my php script, I just keep getting MySQL CONNECTION ERROR:

```
Access denied for user 'main_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have recreated the user more than once and setting the privileges.. i just keep getting denied! :(

I then decided to NOT USE  a password for the DB access 
so created same user main_user but no password
set the privileges

and when i run my script.. i can CONNECT to mySQL but can't access the DB!

```
Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'inventory_main'
```

To rule out my script issues, I ran sqlbuddy and entered the proper user pass and host details and i get the error:
    There was a problem logging you in.

at this point, if i dont use a password i can CONNECT to the mysql server but i get rejected when trying to access the actual database (and yes i have set the privileges for both SERVER and DATABASE to allow main_user)

i can't think of anything else to try.. i feel there must be some sort of setting in mysql or something that i missed here(?)

UPDATE: 06-08-2013 (Saturday) @ 10:03 AM

here's the screenshot of the PHPMYADMIN priveledges
http://d.pr/i/IyOZ

and here's the sshot of the php config file
http://d.pr/i/hyxP

I double checked the username, password and granted all privs to the target table as well as global

I THINK THERE's REALLY SOMETHING WRONG w/ the DATABASE (engine, configuration, etc)

because
1) if I edit the mYSQL user, and change the user from "main_user" to "hello_user" for example.. EVERYTHING WORKS!!!!!! 
2) if i edit it back , then i get the access denied error

why is this? seems like a conflict of some sort?

the only clue i have is that the "main_user" is the user account on the old server.. this is a new install i didnt import any users or privs! all i carried over was the DB DUMP from the old server

Comment: Chances are you overlooked something. Look at **everything** again. It may take time, but it just might be worth it.

Comment: how hard could it be? create table, create user for it and set privileges.. but i dont mind goin through it again and again so long as someone can confirm that there isnt anyhthing outside of that scope.. like a mysql switch to ALLOW users other than ROOT or something weird like that

Comment: I don't know about MySQL, but if you created a login in SQL Server and used a backup from another server to create a database locally, and it had the same *named* user granted rights, etc., the user access wouldn't work.  Why? The user in the database wouldn't have the same id of the newly created login in SQL Server... you'd have to set either the login user id to match the database user id or the other way around.

Comment: Can you update the question to include the *exact* method you used to create the user, include all steps please. I believe the error is there.

Comment: @jayC, thanks but i recreated the users and priviledges.. it was a clean install of mysql and restured just the TABLE / DBs, user/privs were re-created.

@ Tigger , hmm.. perhaps but i tried it many times. under phpmyadmin, create user, .. done.. then add priv of that user to target DB and grant all .. done..  but still access denied. im "this" close to reinstalling wamp lol

Answer (score 2):

"I set the mysql USER (main_user) and PASS (aa11) properly for a DB w/ the right privileges (grant all)"

Without seeing which commands you typed, it's very likely that you overlooked something in your configuration. For example, did you know that there's no such thing as a user called "main_user", because in MySQL all user accounts must have a host (so valid usernames could include main_user@localhost or main_user@%). If you are unwilling to post all of the commands you entered, your best bet is to read the MySQL docs on the GRANT command. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html

Comment: i meant i set the username to "main_user" as my standard username.. and yes i've set the hosts properly (% = anyhosts) .. i can't be mistaken w/ the username and pass and host setup since.. i'm using a DB administrator to set the usernames .. and i even tried PHPMYADMIN ..  

ill update my post .. sorry for the late reply i was out of town.